# NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields is not all. Need exact response message

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

My server returns code 401 but in response message string it also gives description in more details (why auth might be failing)

In Android I use

```
response.Message = httpsURLConnection.getResponseMessage();
response.Code = httpsURLConnection.getResponseCode();
```

and get correct response message. In iOS with NSURLSession I can't seem to be able to get a hold of truly raw response headers.

All I have is localizedStringForStatusCode but this is not what server returning.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: and NSHTTPURLResponse's [`allHeaderFields`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPURLResponse/allHeaderFields) doesn't give you what you want?

Comment: No. There is no response message in there. I guess framework is being smart about this specific header..

Comment: The responds code and response message aren't part of the headers, they're part of the response status (the "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" message.  Putting additional non-standard content on that line probably isn't a particularly good idea.  A better idea would be for the server to actually put the additional content in a real header field, "X-MyCompanyName-FailureReason: because you're ugly" or some such.  To answer the question more precisely, the response message doesn't seem to be available as part of `NSHTTPURLResponse`  It's not in `allHeaderFields` because it isn't a header.

Comment: We were hoping to do iOS version without changes to server API :( It will work as is, I guess I can pre-code for "future" header so if server API changes iOS version will start showing better messages